# Generete page with checked and unchecked checkboxes without java script

Tags: asp.net, html, checkbox

I have asp.net mvc page with big amount of data that presented as checkboxes. Some of them are checked other not. I have code like this

```
@if(item.IsSelected)
{
    <input id="@item.Name" name="@item.Code" type="checkbox" checked/>
}
else
{
    <input id="@item.Name" name="@item.Code" type="checkbox"/>
}
```

It works. But to my mind looks crappy. I'm looking for way to set attribute checked to something like `unchecked` or `false` or `0` or `-1` or any value that allows me write it more short.
Like next:

```
<input id="@item.Name" name="@item.Code" type="checkbox" checked="@item.IsSelected?"checked":"what?!!"/>
```

Note. I want to find a simple way. I don't want to use javaScript or jQuery because it makes the code sophisticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Html helper CheckBoxFor.
You bind it to the properties of your model and it will show checked or unchecked depending on the value of the boolean property it is bound to.

Something like `@Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.item.IsSelected, new { @id = ..., @name= ... })`

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. Frankly I've used CheckBox (not CheckBoxFor) because I'm going to keep my code simple. And I have something like next: @Html.CheckBox(item.Code, item.IsSelected, new {id = item.Name, onchange = "CkeckBlaBlaBla('" + @item.Code + "')"})

Comment: It solved my question. But I'm still interesting - Is any way to solve it by html??

Comment: I guess you could create a helper method that receives the boolean and translates it to "true" or "false". Calling that method in the checked property and passing in the IsSelected would result in the string "true" or "false" being written in the property value. I guess this could also work, but the Html.CheckBox is cleaner.

Comment: You described one more Html.CheckBox )